# I need to hide `Show all bookmarks` button in Safari 6

Tags: safari

I use Safari 6 (on OS X 10.8.3) and I want to hide all button on Bookmarks Bar in Safari 6.

For `Show Reading list` and `Show Top Sites` there are an options to hide it in `Preference → Bookmark` but there is no option for hide `Show all bookmarks` button.

Is there anyway to hide `Show all bookmarks` button on Bookmark Bar in Safari 6 ? I don't want to see it on my browser anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari lets you hide the entire bookmark bar, but not customize that one item.

The other items that show up to the left of all your bookmarks are in a fixed order and you can turn them all off except for the show all bookmarks icon.

[image]

Unless someone finds a hidden preference to write by hand into the safari defaults preferences, you may have to request this as a bug or enhancement request to Apple for Safari.

At best, you're stuck with the space that the back arrow takes on the left of the bookmark bar if you turn off all the other default items.

[image]